# The Server Tag is not well formed - RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, server-tags

I am trying to write a RegularExpressionValidator which checks to make sure the entry into a Textbox is Integer (does not contain "." or ",", only integer values like "500")

But I have encountered this:

```
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
```

The code is as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Paymenttb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID ="PaymentValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Paymenttb" 
ErrorMessage="Payment must be of type Int (No "." or "," for example)." ValidationExpression="^\d+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

What is the problem with this?
I have searched around and cannot find any reason why this is not formed well.

Comment: Your error message contains `"` which is not allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ErrorMessage="Payment must be of type Int (No "." or "," for example)."
```

This part. You have quotes in your quoted parameter.

You can go around that by making the outer quotes single quotes:

```
ErrorMessage='Payment must be of type Int (No "." or "," for example).'
```

Another solution: Escape the quote html-style:

```
ErrorMessage="Payment must be of type Int (No &quot;.&quot; or &quot;,&quot; for example)."
```

"

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that! What an amateur mistake. Thanks a lot. Will mark as answer. I think I have just been looking at the code too long.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ErrorMessage` attribute is not well formed:

```
ErrorMessage="Payment must be of type Int (No "." or "," for example)."
```

You need to escape the `"` in the attribute value - do that by doubling them:

```
ErrorMessage="Payment must be of type Int (No ""."" or "","" for example)."
```

Or, use single quotes to delimit the attribute value:

```
ErrorMessage='Payment must be of type Int (No "." or "," for example).'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Paymenttb" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID ="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Paymenttb"  ToolTip="Payment must be of type Int (No '.' or ',' for example)." ValidationExpression="^\d+$">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

OR

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID ="PaymentValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Paymenttb"  ErrorMessage="Payment must be of type Int (No '.' or ',' for example)." ValidationExpression="[0-9]"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```